# If I am using getSQL in r to read a query from a folder but within the query it takes a oracle parameter how would I approach that?

Tags: r, oracle, shiny, odbc

This is the setup of my folder.

..sqlqueryfolder
..city.sql

This is the query :
SELECT * FROM Country
WHERE dates = :dates

I want to get the query from the sqlqueryfolder where the city sql is that accepts an oracle parameter and I am in the directory.I use this in my R script.

dates <-‘01-June-22’

Qry <- getSQL(“city”,
dates=dates )

However when I try to assign the input dates to dates in the query it is giving an error. This is the error
Error in
`if (!is.null(params) & length(params[params$param == v, "default"]) >  :  argument is of length zero`

Comment: Please do not post (only) an image of code/data/errors: it breaks screen-readers and it cannot be copied or searched (ref: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557 and https://xkcd.com/2116/). Please include the code, console output, or data (e.g., `data.frame(...)` or the output from `dput(head(x))`) directly.

Comment: I have fixed it do you have any feedback on this ?.

Comment: Unfortunately, no. I don't know what `getSQL` is from, and while I'm comfortable with R and SQL access via `DBI` and `odbc`, I suspect that the issue is specific to whatever package defines that function. It's feasible with `DBI`, though, with something like `dbGetQuery(con, "select * from country where dates=?", params=list(dates))`, noting that this is purely _positional_ and not named parameters. See https://db.rstudio.com/best-practices/run-queries-safely/ for more examples.

Comment: Hello @r2evans do you have to put the SQL query in the dbGetQuery() function ? Can the query be stored another place and called in the r script while taking in a parameter ? For instance if the  `select * from country where date =?"`  was stored in a file called city_query , could I call it like this  `dbGetQuery(conn, city_query, "01-APR-22)`. The reason I ask is just because the queries I am working with a way longer than 10 lines and it is best to store in another file then call it to the main script , let me know if you have any feedbacks or idea on how this can be done.

Comment: `dbGetQuery(con, city_query, params="2022-04-01")` works, as does `dbGetQuery(con, city_query, params=list("2022-04-01"))` (necessary if you will have more than one `?` in your query). It seems unlikely to me that `"01-APR-22"` would work in general (it fails on SQL Server, for example), both for the y2k ambiguity and for the nonstandard (internationally/ansi) date format, but `"2022-04-01"` works.

Comment: Hey revans2 , the date would actually be truncated that is why it will be in that format.

Comment: That format is not understood as-is by any DBMS that I know of (I have only tested a few, tbh). If it is truncated somewhere, fix it before sending to the database.